# Installing tensorflow 1.8.0 gpu

Tags: tensorflow

I am installing tensorflow gpu using pip following the instruction on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Which seems to work and indicates that the version 1.8.0 is installed.

The only warning was about pip being not up to date, as recommended I updated pip with the following command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

similarly no error reported.

I tried the hello word (or so far only the first line:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

and I got a long error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
    ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
    % (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
```

I installed Cuda 9.1 as other software packages requires that version. 
While the instructions page indicates Cuda 9.0, links on the instruction page links to Cuda 9.1 on the nvidia site.

So the question is there a way to install with cuda 9.1, or should I wait until another version is available. while browsing other similar question it seems that some time back it was planed for tensorflow 1.5.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm still using TF 1.7, but I had a similar problem in TF 1.7, which only supported cuda 9.0 and failed with cuda 9.1. I suspect that may not have changed in 1.8, but I'm not certain of it.

Comment: how did you make it work with cuda 9.0, you had both 9.0 and 9.1 installed, or did you just kept 9.0?

Comment: Update the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, that's what tensorflow uses to find the appropriate library. But in my case I just uninstalled 9.1 and installed 9.0, but I'm certain that setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is just as useable an option.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not work on Windows but the PATH  :). Anyway just found a blog post solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer there :https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-tensorflow-gpu-windows-cuda-cudnn/

The only thing I did differently is not installing the drivers for CUDA 9.0 (only the CUDA part).